# Creating Custom Login Authentication in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I tried to follow the instruction on other StackOverflow question, but still does not work.
I'm trying to create a custom login authentication using django for my school project. i want the user to login only using their username

Here's my views :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
# Create your views here.
from myatm.newauth import MyBackend

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.POST.get('token')
        print(token)
        user = authenticate(username = token)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
            else:
                print('gagal')
        else:
            print(user) # it always goes here, somehow my authentication failed
    return render(request, 'bank/login.html')
```

here is my custom auth :

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class MyBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

My settings :

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'myatm.newauth.MyBackend', # mybackend auth
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

Note : I already add my custom auth on settings

Comment: Can you expand on what isn't happening that you expect to happen? You may want to show some of your `settings.py` to show you are using your custom auth.

Comment: i expect that the user log in, but somehow doesn't. at first I assume there's something wrong with the login system so I print out the user. turns out it returns none, not the user datas

Comment: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'myatm.newauth.MyBackend', # mybackend auth
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

Answer (score 0):

To see if the user is authenticated or not, just check if the value is not `None` and then login the user. see below code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
# Create your views here.
from myatm.newauth import MyBackend

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.POST.get('token')
        print(token)
        user = authenticate(username = token)

        if user is not None: #check if the value of user variable is not None
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
            else:
                print('gagal')
        else:
            print(user)
    return render(request, 'bank/login.html')
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: that's the problem, the user is always == none

Comment: Then I think the problem is in authenticate method that you have created. check the user as follows `User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()` it will return a  boolean value.

Comment: somehow my custom authetication didnt do anything. it goes to Django's built in auth instead of my custom made. any ideas?

Comment: in `settings.py` do you have loaded in MIDDLEWARE and included in INSTALLED_APPS?